# How to add custom stylesheet to TinyMCE in WordPress via a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to add a custom stylesheet to the TinyMCE editor in a WordPress plugin I am developing. The WP [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_css) tells me to use the mce_css filter, but it does not seam to work.

As soon, as I use the filter, all the theme's custom stylesheets disappears from the editor, but my custom stylesheet is still not there.

See the following two screenshots, the first without the filter, the second with the filter activated:

[image: normal]

[image: filter activated]

Here is my code:

```
class test_plugin {

function __construct($args = array()){

    if ( is_admin() ){
        add_action('admin_head', array( $this, 'admin_head') );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this , 'admin_enqueue_scripts' ) );
    }

}


function admin_head() {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( 'true' == get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'mce_css', 'plugin_mce_css' );
    }

}


function admin_enqueue_scripts(){
     // wp_enqueue_style('fa_icon_shortcode', plugins_url( 'css/mce-button.css' , __FILE__ ) );
}


function plugin_mce_css( $mce_css ) {

    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) )
        $mce_css .= ',';

    $mce_css .= plugins_url( 'editor.css', __FILE__ );

    return $mce_css;

}
```

}

new test_plugin();

Any idea what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It actually was a pretty simple solution. Since I am using OOP, I had to add the filter with

```
add_filter( 'mce_css', array( $this , 'plugin_mce_css' ) );
```

instead of

```
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'plugin_mce_css' );
```

Works like charm!